# Woocommerce product page not showing products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I have moved my Wordpress website from one host to another. Since then I am facing issue with the products in Woocommerce.

For example products are not showing in the backend but showing in the product count. Also on the home page, products are showing but when clicked on a product not showing.

[image]

Comment: Also (once tried to regenerate permalinks like in Aggelos answer) maybe you can try to delete transients in Admin menu > WooCommerce > System Status > Tools… This tool will clear the product/shop transients cache.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? This seems like it could be a PHP issue that has stopped the page from loading. Check your web server error logs too.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this is a permalink issue. Go to dashboard and find settings->permalinks. Choose the one you want and hit save. If the preferred one is already chosen, pick another one, save and pick again the one desired and save again.

This will regenerate .htaccess file and probably fix the problem.